# HTML Quiz - JavaScript Button (Turn Results Green, False Red)

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

NOTE: This is just a snippet of the code I have to write. There are like 8 questions, all of them have the same structure just with a proper "text"

My problem is, I have a quiz in HTML and I need the right / wrong answers to change color accordingly if I click on the button below. I'm new to JS and I'm sorry if this has been answered before. I've spent hours on trying to find a solution for this and asked one of my classmates. I feel like I'm missing something that might be obvious for others.

```html
 /*  What I've already tried:
 x Instead of using "" - used those ''
 x Tried using the div ID 
 x I added "var" infront of the document.getElement(...) and removed it again
 x Tried document.getElement(..).style.Texttransform.color=".." */





/*The HTML Part*/

<div id= "question7">

<form>
<p> Question 7? </p> 

<p><input type = "radio" id = "wrong" name= "question7a" value = "Yes">
 Yes a b c <br></p>

<p><input type = "radio" id = "wrong" name= "question7b" value = "No"
>No, a b c <br></p>

</form>
</div>



/* The Button */

<div id= "send" >

<form>
<input id="change_button" type="button" value="Change" 
onClick="change();"/>

</form>
</div>




/*The Script Part*/

<script>
function change() {

document.getElementbyID("wrong").style.color ="red";
document.getElementbyID("right").style.color ="green";

}
</script>
```

Comment: You are using `document.getElementByID()`, which is incorrect - you have capitalised ID  when it should be Id, and havent capitalised `by`. It should be like this: `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: oh lol. Didn't know it was that simple.. oof TT thank you

Comment: No problem, if you need anymore help, feel free to ask :)

Comment: okay, update: I changed the ID to "Id" and I updated the names of "question7" but it's still not changing colors. I made a whole new html page with the code above where I'm testing it. Also instead of just <script> I changed it to <script type = "text/javascript"> </script> not sure if that makes any difference. This is giving me such a headache ahah

Comment: I've added an answer now that should work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id= "question7">

<form>
<p> Question 7? </p> 

<p id = "wrong" ><input type = "radio"  name= "question7a" value = "Yes">
 Yes a b c </input></p>

<p id = "right"  ><input type = "radio"  name= "question7b" value = "No"
>No, a b c </input></p>

</form>
</div>


<div id= "send" >

<form>
<input id="change_button" type="button" value="Change" 
onClick="change()"/>

</form>
</div>
```

the exact syntax is `document.getElementById` (notice to `ById`) and then put `id="right"` and `id ="wrong"` in `<p>` so your done.
[check this code](https://playcode.io/348128?tabs=script.js,preview,console/)

Comment: I can't believe this worked. Thank you so so much, problem solved. <3

Comment: This code breaks with multiple radio inputs. (try selecting both)

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a few errors. You should name your radio input the same, so they act like radio button (so only one can be selected at a time). You should use labels for the text of these radio buttons, using for to correspond the the id of each radio button. You should then get the id of the *label*, not the input, to change the colour.

```html
<div id="question7">
  <form>
    <p> Question 7? </p>
    <input id="7a" type="radio" name="question7">
    <label id="wrong" for="7a">Yes, a b c</label>
    <br>
    <input id="7b" type="radio" name="question7">
    <label id="right" for="7b">No, a b c</label>
  </form>
</div>
<br>
<div id="send">
  <input id="change_button" type="button" value="Change" onClick="change();" />
</div>

<script>
  function change() {
    document.getElementById("wrong").style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById("right").style.color = "green";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form>
        <p> Question 7? </p> 
        <p><input type = "radio" id = "wrong" name= "question7" value = "Yes">Yes a b c <br></p>
        <p><input type = "radio" id = "right" name= "question7" value = "No">No, a b c <br></p>
    </form>
</div>
<div id= "send" >
    <form>
        <input id="change_button" type="button" value="Change" onclick="change();"/>
        <p id="error_msg" style="display:none;color:red;">Please select the answer</p>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
function change() {
    var questions = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i=0; i< questions.length;i++){
        if(questions[i].type === 'radio' && questions[i].checked){
            document.getElementById("wrong").parentNode.style.color ="red";
            document.getElementById("right").parentNode.style.color ="green";
            document.getElementById('error_msg').style.display = 'none';
            break;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('error_msg').style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id= "question7">
<form>
<p> Question 7? </p>
<p><input type = "radio" id = "wrong" name= "question7" value = "Yes">
 Yes a b c <br></p>
<p><input type = "radio" id = "right" name= "question7" value = "No">No, a b c <br></p>
</form>
</div>
```

The name should be for the both radio buttons. :)